# Are the Node.JS MongoDB sorting/filtering functions available outside the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, filter, filtering

The `MongoDB` sorting functions are pretty neato. Can you use them on objects and/or arrays that have nothing to do with the database itself?

```
var mongo       = require('mongodb'),
    Server      = mongo.Server,
    Db          = mongo.Db,
    sortingFun  = mongo.internalSortFilterFunction(); // By the miracle of imagination, this is a made-up line.
```

There is, for example, [this awesome little node project](https://github.com/crcn/sift.js) called `sift`: *MongoDB inspired array filtering*. But there are more similar tools, different opinions, and projects merging and disappearing.

Considering it's popularity, `MongoDB` is quite probably gonna hang around. For that reason, plus the added bonus of being exactly similar instead of pretty similar, I was wondering if a specific object/model/function within node-mongodb could be linked from the `require('mongodb')` specifically for using the sorting and filtering functions on custom objects/arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting is done in the mongo server, not the client. It's also not particularily fast -- big collections should be pre-sorted, but that's another issue.

The mongo server is afaik written in C++ and uses custom types, separate from the JS engine, called BSON.

So if there is no sort implementation on the client for javascript, which would be an absurd feature, you can't use server sort.

Edit: If you really really want to use the sort, performance be damned, you could insert js objects into the DB, effectively converting them to BSON in mongo collections. Then sort it and pull it from the DB. Indexes etc will need to be recreated for every call to that function. Mongodb also refuses to sort for big collections sans index (limit being somewhere around 1000 I believe)

PS. I haven't read the source. I can't imagine a JS realtime, indexless sort that matches the speed of MongoDB's sort esp. when distributed (sharded). But you can write node.js modules in C++, and if BSON is similar enough to V8 JS objects (wouldn't think so), you might be able to port it. I wouldn't go down that road because it's probably not going to be a big speed increase compared to reimplementing it in JS, a reimplementation which would be a lot easier to create and maintain.

Comment: Thanks. Clear. Except when you have a specific little collection in memory after a Mongo query, and want to filter those in a few different ways, that's were JS based sorting comes in handy, and with a MongoDB-sorting-clone like `sift` you can re-use the filter-objects you would give to MongoDB in the first place.

Comment: Concerning the last line of your edit: Does every sortable field need to be indexed? Does every filterable field need to be indexed?

Comment: @Redsandro Yeah, in-memory sort can be useful in JS, I suppose. But it's very unlikely that mongodb provides that -- the JS  in Mongo is practically just a client.

Regarding sort and filter of indexes: A sortable field /should/ be indexed, but /must/ be indexed when there are too many documents. I don't think the same applies to filtered fields (I've never used filter, but I think it maps to the same as $exists which I use). Index them just to be sure, is what I do.

Comment: `Mongodb also refuses to sort for big collections sans index` do you have a link for this?

Comment: This post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399068/mongodb-too-much-data-for-sort-with-no-index-error details a sorting failure because of a mismatched compound key. It's pretty easy to replicate, create a big collection of `{x: [0..n]}` documents and try to sort on `x`.